# Find the cummulative distribution function and the density function of the random variable: $Y={1\over 1+U}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, proof-verification, random-variables

Let $U$ have a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$. Find the cummulative distribution function and the density function of the random variable: $Y={1\over 1+U}$

My attempt:

$F_Y(x)=P[Y\le x]=P[{1\over 1+U}\le x]=P[1+U\ge {1\over x}]=P[U\ge {1\over x}-1]=1-P[U\lt {1\over x} -1]=1-F_U({1\over x}-1)$

But $F_U(x)= \begin{cases} 0, & \text{if $x<$ 0} \\ x, & \text{if 0$\le x\le$ 1} \\ 1, & \text{if 1$< x$} \end{cases} $

therefore

$F_U({1\over x}-1)= \begin{cases} 0, & \text{if $x<$ 0} \\ {1\over x}-1, & \text{if 0$\le x\le$ 1} \\ 1, & \text{if 1$< x$} \end{cases} $

For the density function:

$$f_Y(x)=F´_Y(x)=F´_U({1\over x}-1)/x^2=f_U({1\over x}-1)/x^2$$

I would really appreciate if you can tell me if this is the correct approach :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is fine, except that you have to be more careful with the domain of the new random variable. Before you start ask yourself what is the domain of $$Y=\frac{1}{1+U}$$ in order to discriminate cases for $y$ in a proper way. Since $U$ takes values in $[0,1]$, obviously $$\frac12\le Y\le 1$$ Therefore $$P(Y\le y)=\begin{cases}0, &y<\frac12\\P(U\ge\frac{1}{x}-1), &\frac12\le y \le 1\\1,&1<y\end{cases}$$ Now, you can proceed as you already have.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Stef :)

Comment: You are welcome @user128422, good luck with it!